# Creating Radio buttons by ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to create radio buttons by ajax response.  Below is my code so far,

```
function loadPaymentMethods(){
    var baseURL = "<?php echo site_url('student/payment_methods'); ?>";
    var controllerURL = baseURL;
      $.ajax({
          url : controllerURL,
          type : 'POST',
          data:{},
          success : function(data){
              alert(data); 

              for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
                //create 2 radio buttons here by looping

             }
         }
        });
}
```

`alert(data);` this output like below,

`[{"id":"1","name":"full"},{"id":"2","name":"part"}]`

I want to loop the responce and create radio buttons in the code. And want to select the first radio buttton by default.

Please Help Me!

Comment: You want to add you `radio` in `html` container ? @tenten

Comment: @simon I want to add radio button in a div(`<div id = "home">)`.

Comment: In your for loop add this `$('#div_id').html('<input type="radio" checked name="'+ i +'" id="'+ i +'"/>');` @tenten

Comment: your getting response as a *data* but your trying the *response.length* take look this

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the radio buttons as html into which ever html element you require.

In the foreach loop:

```
$('#yourelement').html('<input type="radio" checked name="'+ i +'" id="'+ i +'"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your response do this:

```
var response = data;

      for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++){
        $('<input type="radio" name="myradio" id="'+i+'"    
                value="'+response[i].name+'">').appendTo($("#home"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `jQuery.parseJSON()`

note :

1) your getting response as a *data* but your trying the *response.length* take look this

```js
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '[{"id":"1","name":"full"},{"id":"2","name":"part"}]' );
var JJ ="";
var p =1;
$.each(obj,function(i,v)
{
  if(p==1){ concat ="checked"; }else{ concat="" }

 JJ+='<input type="radio" '+concat+' name="'+ v.name +'" id="'+ v.name +'" value="'+ v.id +'"/><br>';
 p++;
});

$('#ss').html(JJ);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ss">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this answer only fisrt radio is checked

```js
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '[{"id":"1","name":"full"},{"id":"2","name":"part"}]' );
var radio_html ="";
var count = 0;
$.each(obj,function(i,v){

  if(count == 0){
    radio_html =radio_html+'<input type="radio" checked name="'+ i +'" id="'+ i +'"/> <span>Radio '+i+'</span><br>';
  }else{
    radio_html =radio_html+'<input type="radio" name="'+ i +'" id="'+ i +'"/><span>Radio '+i+'</span><br>';
  }
 
 count++;
});

$('#home').html(radio_html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a dive with id="myDiv". This will be the code (add it to the success block):

```js
$("document").ready(function () { 
            
            var data = [{id:"1", name:"part"},{id:"2", name:"full"}]
            var $myDiv = $("#myDiv");
              
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                //create 2 radio buttons here by looping
                $myDiv.append('<input type="radio" id="' + data[i].id + '" name="' + data[i].name + '" />');
            }
            
            $('#myDiv input[type=radio]:first').attr('checked', 'checked');
        })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{"id":"1","name":"full"},{"id":"2","name":"part"}],
    html = '';

arr.forEach(function (el, index) {
  var checked = !index ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
  html += '<div>' +
    '<input type="radio" name="select" id="'+el.id+'" value="'+el.id+'" '+checked+'>' +
    '<label for="'+el.id+'">'+el.name+'</label>' +
  '</div>';
});

$('#result').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```